# Understanding Dcast from Reshape2 in R

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a question with regard to melting the data and any idea on how this can be done would be very much helpful.
For example: I have `head(dataset)` like

```
 KLIENDIKAARDINR                 TSEKK_ID        KPV   KPV_ID     KELL
1 9233660006737480 201401250001057986117632 2014.01.25 20140125 18:33:19
2 9233660006737480 201401250001057986117632 2014.01.25 20140125 18:33:19
3 9233660006737480 201401250001057986117632 2014.01.25 20140125 18:33:19
4 9233660006737480 201401250001057986117632 2014.01.25 20140125 18:33:19
5 9233660006737480 201401250001057986117632 2014.01.25 20140125 18:33:19
6 9233660006737480 201401250001057986117632 2014.01.25 20140125 18:33:19
       Categories D_INVENTTABLE_PRODUCT_ID  KL_ID
1      cat1                    103573   538151
2      cat2                   119186    538151
3      cat3                   103573    538154
4      cat5                    99298    538151
5      cat2                   116390    538152
6      cat2                   107954    538151
 where there are 78 different barcodes cat1..cat78
```

and another df contains just unique KL_ID like

```
head(n,2)
KL_ID  margin_total
10     996.1263
558151 122.337 
558152 328.323
 ...   ....
```

Now to reshape the data in this format :

```
KL_ID  margin_total cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5 ...cat78
  10     996.1263   0    0    1     1    0
  558151 122.337    1    1    0     0    1        
  558152 328.323    0    1    0     0    1
```

the logic here is to make cat1..78 as columns and fill them with binary values like with 1 if the exist irrespective of the number of times they occur for each KL_ID and with 0 if this category is not there for the corresponing KL_ID.

Any help on how we can use dcast from reshape to apply on this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: @Heroka :I merge the unique KL_ID with those of the categories and then tried to summarize using ddply for counting the number of occurance of each category for each KL_ID.I could not proceed ahead as this created warnings: NA values inserted due to coercion. However even if I ignore the NAs. I am not sure how I can make 78 columns with the condition if count>1 ?1 :0 
there should be a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: @Prashanth Can you include the code you tried to solve the problem with ?

Comment: @steveb : yeah sure.but I don't know how to proceed after this.
 mer1 <- function(df1 , df2, var1, var2){
  data <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = var1, by.y= var2, all.x = TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
   return(data)
 }

mer2<-mer1(dataset, n ,"KL_ID","KL_ID")

tdata<- ddply(mer2, .(KL_ID,Categories), summarize,count=length(Categories))